# Does webpack splitting good for saving AWS cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, webpack, node-modules

Our website is build with heavy `node_modules`.
Many heavy package cause heavy `node_modules` and eventually affects heavy cost on AWS.
So we are trying to **reduce total bundle size to reduce some cost**.
What I found is, by splitting code with webpack, we can have more but smaller bundles. Though, overall size doesn't change a lot.

What i'm wondering is, **does splitting code with webpack can save some AWS cost?**
Sorry for poor question, but this is all I can think of right now.
Any great idea would very helpful Thx.

Comment: Are you using cloudfront+S3 or S3 Websites feature? Can you describe your caching strategy?

Comment: @MisterSmith Yes we are using cloudfront and s3. We build our website and put them in S3, deliver by cloudfront. Problem i'm dealing with is assets that saved in s3 causes heavy cost.

Comment: If S3 is your biggest cost with S3+CloudFront i would say you need to look at your caching strategy in general before looking at any specific optimizations to get the most benefit. Check Cloudfront stats on cache hits/misses and confirm what default cache headers are being applied to your static resources. It sounds like your static assets are not cached long enough - if so your changes to WebPack might not make much difference to your cost.

Comment: @MisterSmith Thank you! That would be a great way to save some cost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complex topic and equally open-ended question too! To answer this, I will make few assumptions:

- By saving AWS cost, it means reducing bundle size so that outgoing bandwidth cost is saved.
- Application being built is 100% SPA i.e. fully client-side. Server-side optimization gets very complex quickly.

Out of box, Webpack will bundle everything into one big file/bundle. It contains your own code as well as code from third-party libraries. **The fundamental idea here is that third-party code rarely changes while our own code frequently changes.**

So, we can use Webpack to split our code into two distinct chucks using [SplitChunksPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/). One for our own code and another for third-party code i.e. code from `node_modules` folder; lets call it vendor bundle. Now as long as your `node_modules` folder remains constant i.e. your lock file - `package-lock.json` file is constant, it will always produce the same bundle with exact same content for third-party code.

**Then next part of the idea** is that you can simply take this vendor bundle and upload it to CDN and then use via CDN. The CDN and browser will do their caching magic and users will hardly need to download this file each time. CDN will use `ETag` and/or `cache-control` header to achieve this and browser will use that.

However, the reality is different. When you have too many dependencies and or using **dependabot** to update dependencies, you will often update your lock file. This means on each build a new vendor bundle gets generated even if there is a difference of single byte. The hash id generated by Webpack will be different. And in other scenario, the way you import the dependencies may also change the generated bundle content resulting in a different bundle.

So, **architecturally, we do better vendor bundling by making use of CDNs**. The first step is to distinguish between **stable third-party module and frequently updated third-party module**. For example, consider `react`, `react-dom` and `rxjs`, etc. These are not updated often. For these libraries, make use of third-party CDN like cloudflare, cdnjs or unpkg. Add these libraries as CDN based UMD packages.

For this, you will add these dependencies to your `index.html` file which is typically generated using `html-webpack-plugin`.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Now, simply tell Webpack to not bundle these dependencies which you have already made available via CDN `script`. Use Webpack [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) to do that:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  
  externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
  },
};
```

With this configuration, Webpack is not only going to exclude React from the bundle but also will speed up your bundling. Where ever you import stuff from react library, Webpack will substitute this for global object `React`.

You can then extend this model to all the stable libraries that you are using. **Another important advantage of using this way is that there would be other websites that your users may have already visited which would have cached this particular file in their browser using the same CDN.**

To automate your workflow, you can customize Webpack or any bundler script to inject these scripts with exact version by reading the `packge.json` file for your dependencies and then generating the `<script>` tags. It means you would still have single source of truth for your dependencies versions. You can read [CDN documentation](https://unpkg.com/) to understand how they allow you to construct CDN URLs for the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. CDN would be great solution!